# Why if $\mathbb E[XY]=0$ and $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian, then $X$ and $Y$ are independant?

Tags: probability

Why if $\mathbb E[XY]=0$ and $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian, then $X$ and $Y$ are independant ? I know that if $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]$ and $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But I don't see why if $\mathbb E[XY]=0$ it's independent.

Comment: It is not true. It would be true if either $E[X]=0$ or $E[Y]=0$.

Comment: Take any jointly distributed Gaussian vectors $(X,Y)$ such that $E[Y]\neq 0$ and $X, Y$ are not independent.   Define $Z = X - E[XY]/E[Y]$. Then $E[ZY]=0$, $(Z,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian, but 
$Z$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you really mean $E(X_1 X_2) = E(X_1) E(X_2)$ , or you are assumming the variables have zero mean. 
Otherwise, the property is obviously false.

$(X,Y)$ are (jointly) Gaussian if their density follow the (multivariate) [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). This depends on $\Sigma$, the covariance matrix, which has in its off-diagonal elements the covariance of each pair of components. It's immediate that if the components are uncorrelated ($E(X_1 X_2) = E(X_1) E(X_2)$) then the covariance is zero, then $\Sigma$ is diagonal, then the density can be factored in a product of unidimensional Normal distributions - hence the components are independent.

Alternatively: writing doen the [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2), it's readily seen that $\rho=0$ implies $E(X_1 \mid X_2) = E(X_2)$ which implies $E(X_1 X_2) = E(X_1) E(X_2)$

Comment: $$inmediate$$..

Comment: @mathworker21 : what?

Comment: you said "inmediate" instead of "immediate". i live a boring life

Comment: aaah... Spanish contamination ... fixed, thanks!